# `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found but it is there

Tags: c++, libstdc++, libc++

I got the error

```
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found
```

I have installed the following rpm file: `https://centos.pkgs.org/6/nux-dextop-i386/chrome-deps-stable-3.11-1.i386.rpm` because there are `GLIBCXX_3.4.14` and `GLIBCXX_3.4.15` versions for centOS6.

```
[cloudera@quickstart Downloads]$ strings
/opt/google/chrome/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.0
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.1
GLIBC_2.1.3
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBC_2.2
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

I have linked this folder to libstdc++.so

```
[cloudera@quickstart DataGenLinux]$ ln -s /opt/google/chrome/lib/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6
[cloudera@quickstart DataGenLinux]$ ./myFile.out -h 
./DataGen.out: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not
found (required by ./DataGen.out)
./DataGen.out: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not**
found (required by ./DataGen.out)
```

I have defined and exported LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

```
[cloudera@quickstart DataGenLinux]$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/opt/google/chrome/lib/libstdc++.so.6
```

**SOLVED**

```
 mv /usr/lib64/libsrdc++.so.6 /usr/lib64/libsrdc++.so.6_bkp
 mv /opt/google/chrome/lib/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib64/libsrdc++.so.6
```

This solved my issue

Comment: Please do not just download random libraries from random places on the internet to try to solve issues. This will usually just cause more issues.

Comment: Also, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should be set for debugging purposes only. If you have to set it for any other reason than *temporarily* linking a specific library binary *for a specific debugging run*, your system is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should point to a path, not a library.

This should work for you:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/google/chrome/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./myFile.out -h
```

Alternatively,

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/google/chrome/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
./myFile.out -h
```

Note this does not involve any symlinking nor replacing system libraries.

Since libstdc++ (and glibc as well) are forward compatible, it is best to compile/link against the oldest version you want to support (if of course you are in control of `myFile.out`).

It is definitely better to look for a proper CentOS6 package of that version of libstdc++ you need. But even then you'll need to point your loader to it, as it will not replace the system `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6`, rather live alongside it.
You don't provide much context so I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish with what exactly.

Comment: Thanks!
I am trying to run BigBench benchmark and the first step i to generate the data with the following .out file https://github.com/t-ivanov/BigBenchV2/blob/master/DataGenLinux/DataGen.out

Comment: I have updated my question, unfortunately, your suggestions don't work.

Comment: Is the libstdc++.so you downloaded 32 or 64-bit? Why are you using CentOS anyway? It's a thing made for servers or rock-stable corporate machines, not your daily driver by far.

Comment: I can't find any other library which provides the needed versions...

Comment: It is a 64-bit.

Comment: It then seems that you binary is linked to the full path and you're pretty much screwed. You'll either need to physically (or through a symlink) replace /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 with the file you downloaded (which I don't recommend) or use a less stale distribution (or update your CentOS to a newer version and hope the ABI versions you need are present there).

Comment: How can I replace it through a symlink?
ln -s /my/real/path libstdc++.so   or   ln -s /my/real/path /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so ?

Comment: I wanted to upgrade centOS but on the Cloudera VM seemed not so easy.. it didn't work, so, therefore, I am trying to solve it somehow with centOS6...

Comment: Replacing a symlink can be done with `ln -sf`. This only works (I think) if the original file is also a symlink. Otherwise you'll need to remove the original or just copy the new one over. Note this might completely bork your system so make sure you have a quick way to (externally) reset your OS.

Comment: I solved it with your help :)
First: mv /usr/lib64/libsrdc++.so.6  /usr/lib64/libsrdc++.so.6_bkp      Second: mv /opt/google/chrome/lib/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib64/libsrdc++.so.6